# Cache View Controller

Tags: ios, iphone, debugging, background, reboot

While working in `iOS` I see a difference between my app and Apples default app in iPhone. My app name is `MyApp` which i built on objective C and I compared the behavior with Apple's default apps i.e. `Notes`.

I used both apps without suspending. When the device gets rebooted, I see both `MyApp` and `Notes` are shown in the recent list but when I open `MyApp` from the recent list it restarts from the splash screen unlike the system app 
 (Notes) which still stays in the old screen (the screen it was showing before device reboot). Anyone knows what is the reason of different behavior? Do I need to implement any extra step to get the similar behavior like Apples default apps?

Answer (score 1):

This behavior doesn't come automatically. You have to save and restore the UI state in your app.
Apple has lots of documentation on this topic; I recommend to start here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/preserving_your_app_s_ui_across_launches

Comment: Lets say i have used a single db connection which is established once my app open and used several times. Is that connection still preserved  after system reboot or i need to reestablish the connection? The link you referred only talks about the ui preservation.

Answer (score 1):

## View Controller State Restoration

State Restoration in iOS was introduced back in 2012 and major improvements happened in 2013. iOS handles a lot when it comes to State Restoration. When State Restoration is enabled in the application, iOS takes care of the following:

- Maintaining the navigation controller and thereby the navigation hierarchies.
- Maintaining the state of tab bar controllers like selected tabs, etc.
- Building up and restoring view controllers which have opted for state restoration.
- Provides an encrypted archive space to encode the data to and decode the data from.
- If controllers are built from storyboard with restoration opted in the storyboard itself, UIKit helps in saving the controllers and providing controller references and restoring.

Doesn’t that seem easy !! iOS doing almost all the tricky things.

## Integration

Integration in your code can be broken down into the following parts:

## AppDelegate

In AppDelegate, we have to enable state restoration for our application by implementing two delegate methods:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, shouldSaveApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool {
  return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, shouldRestoreApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool {
  return true
}
```

## ViewControllers

ViewControllers are the ones that are to be saved and restored. They are the components which handle the user state in the app. So logically, controllers are the ones which are responsible to save and restore the state of the controllers. So how to do that?

### Restoration ids:

In order to have restoration enabled for a controller, we have to provide a restoration identifier to the class as:

```
self.restorationId = “Your Restoration Id”
```

We could directly set this in storyboard in the attributes inspector as below
[image]

> Note: If you are not providing Restoration ID for any controller it
>   will be excluded from the restoration process, including all
>   controllers in the navigation hierarchy after this controller.

### Restoration Class

A restoration class is a class which knows how to create a specific view controller. This class should conform to UIViewControllerRestoration protocol.
UIStateRestoring protocol
Each class by default confirms to **UIStateRestoring** protocol. This protocol has delegate methods and properties to help controller save relevant information to build up the UI.

```
//Encoding and Decoding the Object
func encodeRestorableState(with: NSCoder)
//Encodes state-related information for the object.
func decodeRestorableState(with: NSCoder)
//Decodes and restores state-related information for the object.
func applicationFinishedRestoringState()
//Called after all objects have had a chance to decode their state.
```

### UIViewControllerRestoration Protocol

The methods that objects adopt so that they can act as a “restoration class” for view controllers during state restoration.
Any class that adopts to this protocol provides a reference of the controller at the time of restoration. View controller should assign this class as its restoration class.

```
//Creating the View Controller
static func viewController(withRestorationIdentifierPath: [String], coder: NSCoder) -> UIViewController?
//Asks the receiver to provide the view controller that corresponds to the specified identifier information.
Required.
```

> Note: Conformance to `UIViewControllerRestoration` protocol is
>   generally not needed if we are building your controllers from
>   storyboard as the reference of the view controllers is taken from the
>   storyboard by `UIKit` at time of restoration. But if we are building
>   your controller programmatically, you have to implement the protocol
>   by yourself.

### Save Data

We have been familiar with UIStateRestoring Protocol above. For saving data UIKit provides us with the following delegate method:

```
func encodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder)
```

We encode the data that we need to restore the controller via the coder corresponding to a key.

> Note: Apple recommends to save minimal data i.e actually necessary for
>   recreating a view controller. Eg. You want to restore the User Details
>   page. So the data that you need to save is the user id and then make a
>   database query to fetch the details and recreate the view controller.
>   This is because the encrypted archive that Apple uses to store the
>   data can be cleaned anytime if the OS deems necessary. So any relevant
>   data will be lost.

### Restore Data

For restoring data, we have to implement the following delegate method:

```
func decodeRestorableState(with: NSCoder)
```

This method is called when UIKit needs to restore the view controller. Here we ask the coder to fetch us the data that we saved and then our normal set up methods should set the UI. The coder has additional information such as versions

For Orignal Article Click [Here](https://medium.com/swift-india/app-state-restoration-in-ios-1-bbc903f17a46)

Comment: Lets say i have used a single db connection which is established once my app open and used several times. Is that connection still preserved after system reboot or i need to reestablish the connection?

Comment: I haven't test it with DB. I think you should preserve the dbModel along ViewController & when your app restart just re-connect with DB.

Comment: App is not restarting. Device is restarting. So no point of reconnecting db.